# Chrome in Windows previous Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.3) : "Most visited" sites in the taskbar Jump List don't match those in the New Tab page

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, jumplist

Deleting a frequent site in the new tab should remove that site from the jumplist (at least in Chrome, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/984002/how-to-remove-particular-most-visited-frequent-sites-in-browsers-jumplists)). But it is not my case; see:

[image: Chrome Taskbar Jumplist]

The first 4 links you can see in the Taskbar Jumplist above (from "Últimas noticias" to "Google News")  were removed from the corresponding New Tab Page shortcuts (below), but the deletions are not being propagated to the "jump list" (above) - the pic above was also taken *after* the deletion of those 4 links.

[image: Chrome New Tab shortcuts]

Yet this problem happens with "just" two of my 3 Google Chrome users. Here is a pic of how both link lists match each other in the "unproblematic" user (it is the default one in case it matters):

[image: "healthy" Chrome user jumplist and New Tab page]

How can I make the changes in the Chrome New Tab page links for those other 2 Chrome users to be propagated to their corresponding Windows jumplist as they should?

I'm using Windows 10

Comment: i meant "I just hope the answer not to be 'try reinstalling windows-10 and see if it works".

Comment: Uninstalling one of these Chrome users and installing it again doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest big Windows 10 update, Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.3), has fixed it.

Comment: Can you possibly expand your answer to highlight the exact update?

Comment: There is just one big update at the moment (I know "big" is relative but thats how the press talked about this one). The id number for the update is Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.3) and it was released in November. Progressively though, so maybe some saw it in December.

Comment: The reason I asked was to help people in the future when there could have been several "big" updates. I know they could probably infer the relevant update from the timestamps but the clarification helps massively.